# Ionic native InAppBrowser: how to add event listener

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm using [InAppBrowser](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/) in my Ionic project the problem is adding new event listener as in the documentation of ionic-native is not working at all, I referred to original [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html#inappbrowserremoveeventlistener) and none of these events are working, I know this is issue from Ionic wrapping side and their poor documentation, they change the whole way of calling plugin and you need to try until you get the right way.

**So I'm asking how to add the event listeners to `InAppBrowser` plugin?**

**What I tried until now is:**

```
var _options = 'location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,hardwareback=no';
function openLink(url, target, options) {
  if (angular.isUndefined(options)) {
    options = _options;
  }
  if (!$window.cordova) {
    $window.open(url, '_blank', options);
  } else {
    _attachEvents(new $cordovaInAppBrowser(url, target, options));
  }
}

function _attachEvents(browser) {
  // FIXME this is not working seems, need to find documentation about this
  browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(function (e, event) {
    console.debug(e, event);
    if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
      browser.close();
    }
    $rootScope.$broadcast('$ionicParentView.enter');
  });
  browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(function (e, event) {
    console.debug(e, event);
    browser.close();
    $rootScope.$broadcast('$ionicParentView.enter');
  });
}
```

And tried ngCordova way:

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function (e, event) {
  if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
  }
  $rootScope.$broadcast('$ionicParentView.enter');
});
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function (e, event) {
  $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();
  $rootScope.$broadcast('$ionicParentView.enter');
});
```

And they are not working, BTW, it was working with ngCordova but since I changed to ionic-native, it stopped working at all.

I'm using Ionic 1.3.2 with ionic-native 2.2.16 (since 2.2.17 and 2.3.0 are broken builds)